# Constantly-on speech recognition listening for just one keyword

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I have tried to code this with Android's included android.speech.SpeechRecognizer class with no success.

Basically, what I am trying to do is making my app constantly listen for one keyword that will fire an intent whenever the keyword is recognized. *I know* that this will use a lot of battery.

For example - you are talking with a person. Normal conversation. The phone is actively listening and recognizing every single said word and listening for the keyword.

Let's say the keyword is "cheese" in this instance.

Whenever you say "cheese," the application fires an intent that starts up another part of the app.

I have tried to use speech recognition as a service but things didn't really go as planned. Maybe I did a mistake, I don't know.

I've been trying to accomplish this for 2 days in a row now, for more than 24 hours work time combined. If I am being too broad or infringing any of  SO's rules, I sincerely apologize and ask my question to be deleted.

My question is - how would this be possible? Of course the SpeechRecognition that is included with android itself would be *preferable*, but it definitely will be a hassle because it is not even designed to work for extended periods.

Comment: Consider CMUSphinx, but actually the best solution depends on the details you didn't provide. For example, should it be an arbitrary word or some predefined word. Do you want to let user record the word for spotting or you want some predefined keyphrase or random keyphrase user types. What languages do you need to support.

Comment: It will be a predefined word. Recording the word and checking input with the recorded file isn't really that accurate I reckon. I need it to be spot-on. English only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

from my research, there is no way to do this using the standard google voice recognition server. They way it works is once sound/word is recognized, the recognizer returns a list of what it thinks it heard with an associated confidence score.

to do what you are asking, you would:

1. have to keep re-activating the recognition service every time it fired a recognition event, until it matches the word you want.
2. your app would have to 'keep-awake' the recognition service. you could do this by creating a service that periodically wakes up your handset and resuming the service/activity.

I would not recommend either of these options considering that the battery life is really reduces by the voice recognition service being constantly on.

Comment: But then what other option would be possible? I've researched other possible speech recognition APIs to no avail.

Comment: most apps that I've seen (including one of mine) rely on the user to initiate the voice recognizer, either manually or, in my case, as a response to a speech synthesizer. for example, click here to say something, or "do you want to say something?".

Comment: How does Google Search do it then?  It continuously listens for "OK Google"

Comment: you still have to gesture (swipe up). this initiates the voice recognition. AFAIK, it is not continuous.

Comment: AFAIK, touchless control is currently only available on some Motorola handsets with KitKat or above. From my understanding, this is because those handsets have an extra circuit/chipset/handware support for constantly listening for voice commands.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I do not think there are any native Android APIs that will fully suit your needs. I would recommend checking out [pocketsphinx](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx).
It is a pretty robust speaker-independent speech recognition API from CMU that is more intended for tasks such as this. You can also check out a tutorial for getting started [here](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid).

Comment: pocketsphinx library is not liable for android. It is not capturing clear words as "OK Google". Is there any other library?

Answer (score 0):

Google has not made API support for "OK GOOGLE" public and left it on vendors to change or pass the support to consumers.
I think best bet at this time would be build source code yourself and then call the API's. As an example below google library has low level details of implementing recognizer. I'm not sure why google does not made it public.
I don't see an easy way to implement and test it.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/speech/srec/Recognizer.java